# Run-time looking for old version of DLL even though new DLL version is present

Tags: c#, windows, dll

We are creating an Autodesk Revit add-in. It's a custom DLL which references other DLLs, including DLLs provided by Google Compute Platform, specifically Google Cloud Storage API DLLs. The application was working fine when we were using 1.35.0 version of Google DLLs. Today we upgraded those DLLs to version 1.38.0 via NuGet. The application compiles fine. But during run-time, it still looks for the old version 1.35.1, which has been uninstalled, even though 1.38.0 DLL sits right there. As a result, the application throws an exception that it couldn't find the DLL.

I am guessing that it's a very small config that I need to change somewhere but I am not familiar with. Any ideas?

Comment: I typed 1.35.0 by mistake. The old Google DLLs had version 1.35.1 and that's what the application is still looking for.

Comment: Do you have more than one project on your solution? Those any other project have a reference to version 1.35.1? Did you try deleting the package folder on your root solution folder and restore Nugget packages again?

Comment: Yes, I do have more than one project but I changed reference in all of them. I also tried deleting the packages and re-installing but it still didn't work.

Comment: Did you try to find "1.35.1" in your entire project. Last resource lol..

Comment: Yes, I did. I grep'ed. But the only matching files were the binary files. The issue persisted even after I deleted the binary files and reloaded the project.